# Speed up the nested for loops in c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, for-loop, datatable

I wrote a program and it's working fine. But the thing is, It's taking much time to process. 
I'm having more then millions data in a data table. So really its very hard to wait till the process complete. I hear something about LinQ method. But i'm not familiar in that. Can any one help me to speed up my code.

```
foreach (var ch in lsCh)
{
    foreach (var dt in lsDt)
    {
        foreach (var cs in lsCs)
        {
            DataRow[] result = Dtsrc.Select("Channel = '" + ch.ToString() + "' AND Date = '" + dt.ToString() + "' AND CPSTime = '" + cs + "'");

            if (result.Length > 0)
            {
                //Some calculation
            }

            Dtsrc.AcceptChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are `lsCh`,`lsDt` and `lsCs`? What are you trying to do there? You cannot throw in some code and say: improve. LINQ also uses loops, normally it just can help to improve readability

Comment: In order to help you, you should provide some informations about the algorithm and the data your are iterating.

Comment: Those are list.! I'm trying to filter the data with this list from the data table@TimSchmelter

Comment: @Shanmugarajan: what kind of lists? What do they contain, how do the classes look like? Also, what is the logic for your for-loops and if conditions? For example: `if (result.Length <= l + 1)` and `for (int rr = resRcnt; rr <= l; rr++)`. Why do you need those three lists at all?

Comment: It's containg channel , date and Start time. the same details are there in data table. with this list in want to get the data from data table.

Comment: @TimSchmelter : the calculation part not taking a time i guess. getting the data from data table  only taking the time. I have edited my code again. please look into same!

Comment: @Shanmugarajan: what are the types of the columns in the DataTable?

Comment: @Shanmugarajan The thing is that from your code it seems like you want to take every possible triple of values from the three lists and do something. If this is the case I'm afraid LinQ can't help you. You don't show any searching logic or some kind of condition. If you want everything just create another table that has everything and get all values.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: column channel , date and startTime having string , dateTime , dateTime types

Comment: @AnastasiosSelmanis : Yep. may be that's good idea. To reduce the loop , i'll create a new table and then try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the types of the DataColumns and the lists are not clear you might have to change them accordingly. But maybe this shows you a more efficient way anyway:

I would use `HashSet<T>` instead of `List<T>`. If you can't change the type in general you could create instances by passing the lists to the constructor:

```
var setCh = new HashSet<int>(lsCh);
var setDt = new HashSet<DateTime>(lsDt);
var setCs = new HashSet<DateTime>(lsCs);
```

Now this query should be much more efficient:

```
var rowsToProcess = Dtsrc.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => setCh.Contains(r.Field<int>("Channel")) && setDt.Contains(r.Field<DateTime>("Date")) && setCs.Contains(r.Field<DateTime>("CPSTime")));

foreach (DataRow row in rowsToProcess)
{
    //Some calculation
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It's working good. Sorry for making you confuse.!